# Make PyCharm autocomplete arguments of super’s method

Tags: python, autocomplete, pycharm

Consider the following code:

```
class A:
  def __init__(self, foo=None):
    pass

class B(A):
  def __init__(self, bar=None, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

When I start typing `B(`, PyCharm helpfully shows `bar` in the autocomplete windows, quick doc, etc. However, it does not show `foo`.

I have resorted to making `foo` an explicit argument of class `B`, but this gets highly repetitive since I have a lot of such arguments. I would like to avoid doing so while still having PyCharm show me all the arguments.

How can I make PyCharm do this?

Comment: Why in the world is that other question considered (even nearly) equivalent to this one?  This  one is about _Pycharm_ and has a completely different approach to the title and is different in perspective.  The choice of setting duplicates is often the most perplexing of close reasons on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short anwser is you can't. This is due to the fact that PyCharm does not not run your code while you type. Python is a dynamic language with multi inheritance, it would be difficult for IDE to check for all parameters in all base classes, especially due the fact that unlike in Java call to the base class `__init__()` function can be omitted.

Also note that this fragment:

```
class B(A):
  def __init__(self, bar=None, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

Enforces that `foo` can only be passed as keyword argument not a positional one, while class A allows it to be passed as positional argument.

However, if typing is an issue i would suggest ctrl+O which is a shortcut to override. If you do it in an empty class it will create an `__init__()` method with arguments from the base class and a call to super. If the documentation is an issue just write a docstring for the method